# The getter 'zyear' isn't defined for the class for 'DateTime'

Tags: flutter, dart

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/intl-0.16.1/lib/src/intl/date_format_field.dart:399:21: Error: The getter 'zyear' isn't defined for the class 'DateTime'.

- 'DateTime' is from 'dart:core'.
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'zyear'.
  var year = date.zyear;

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: It sounds like you somehow accidentally modified `C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\intl-0.16.1\lib\src\intl\date_format_field.dart` and replaced `date.year` with `date.zyear`.